# Elliptic regularity on intervals

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $I = ]a,b[ \subset \mathbf{R}$ be a bounded interval, and $L = \partial^n + c_{n-1} \partial^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 \partial + c_0$, where $c_i \in C^\infty(\overline I)$.
Suppose $u \in L^2(I)$ is such that $L u \in L^2(I)$, where $Lu$ is defined in the sense of distributions.
Show that $u \in H_n(I)$.

I know how to deal with this when the coefficients are $0$:
by induction on $n$, we can show that the solutions of $\partial^n u = 0$ in $L^2(I)$ are just polynomials of order at most $n-1$. Then suppose $u \in L^2(I)$ is such that $\partial^n u = f \in L^2(I)$. Write
$$
v(x) = \int_a^x \int_a^{s_1} \cdots \int_a^{s_{n-1}} f(s_n) \; d s_n \ \cdots d s_2 \; d s_1,
$$
then $v \in H_n(I)$ and $\partial^n v = \partial^n u$, hence $u = v + p$ for some polynomial $p$.

However, I'm stuck in the general case. I'm aware of various elliptic regularity theorems, however, this question is from an introductory text on distribution theory and is asked before such theorems are discussed. So I think there should be a more elementary proof...

Comment: Can you please specify the book that you are reading?

Comment: "Distributions and operators" by Gerd Grubb. This is exercise 4.10 in the text.

Comment: I'm gonna do an example, maybe it can help you. Suppose $L=u''+u'+1$. Then you have that for all $\phi\in C_0^\infty$ $$-\langle u',\phi'\rangle=\langle u,\phi'\rangle +\langle u,\phi\rangle +\langle f,\phi\rangle$$. Now, you can find $v_1,v_2\in H^1$, such that $\langle v_1,\phi'\rangle=\langle u,\phi\rangle$ and $\langle v_2,\phi'\rangle=\langle f,\phi\rangle$. From this you can conclude that $$-\langle u',\phi'\rangle=\langle u,\phi'\rangle +\langle v_1,\phi'\rangle +\langle v_2,\phi'\rangle$$ From this, you have that $u'\in L^2$, which implies that $u\in H^1$ (continued)

Comment: Now that you know $u\in H^1$, you have that $$\langle u,\phi''\rangle=\langle -u'+u+f,\phi\rangle$$ which implies that $u''=-u'+u+f\in L^2$, so by definition $u\in H^2$.